# Is it okay to have <canonical> outside the <head> tag?

Tags: seo, canonical-url, rel-canonical, technical-seo

Is it completely fine to add `rel=canonical` tag outside the head section?

I ran a website audit and the crawler highlighted the issue to have `rel=canonical` tag inside the head tag.

Comment: Do you know if the canonical is being set by a plugin or by the theme you are using?

Answer (score 3):

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/consolidate-duplicate-urls

The following text is highlighted in the official Google documentation:

> If you use a CMS, such as WordPress, Wix, or Blogger, you might not be
> able to edit your HTML directly. Instead, your CMS might have a search
> engine settings page or some other mechanism to tell search engines
> about the canonical URL. Search for instructions about modifying the
> `<head>` of your page on your CMS (for example, search for "wordpress set the canonical element")

This means that we need to put the codes that I want to notify the Google bot between `<head>`.

So in this case, your code should be located between  codes.

```html
<head>
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/url">
</head>
```

Comment: It's easy enough to find the code and put it into header.php in whatever theme you are using. I would consider that a temporary fix. It will go away when you update the theme.

Comment: @keepkalm Yes, you are right, I quoted it because it says add to head.html in this text because it writes a text about where we should add the code in the Google documentation. In fact, they gave another answer in another answer.

Comment: I think your answer is correct, just wanted to add some context regarding CMS and future updates. Canonical could be set by a plugin also. 

I run into this all the time with a plugin I use that uses job schema incorrectly, I fix it, left a note for the developer, hope it gets fixed in a future version.

Comment: @keepkalm Yes, you are right and thank you.